# Loading a notebook to a website

Tags: notebooks

When I upload a Mathematica notebook to my website, when I click on the link, it opens, but as text, not a Mathematica notebook.

At some sites, when I click on a Mathematica notebook, the notebook seems to open in my browser.

Is there some difference here in how the notebook is uploaded to the website?

Thanks.

Comment: Yes, those other websites use the CDF format. Go to the menu and choose File -> CDF Export -> Web embeddable and follow the instructions. Also be advised that the file will only open for those that have the CDF player installed on their systems.